# Create dynamic inner join with multiple column on SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a dynamic query with an inner join inside.

I have a temp table  #table2 with column name

```
| ColumnName  |
---------------
| column1     |
| column2     |
| column3     |
```

My query should looks like this :

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN #table2 t2 ON t2.column1 = t1.column1 AND t2.column2 = t1.column2.......
```

the thing is that i don't know in advance how many column i will have in my temp #table2 so i have to be able to add :

```
  AND t2.column4 = ....
  AND t2.column5 = ....
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi i think you can build your dynamic with using (string_agg / concat into variable and Exec commande) . Please provide your SQL server version string_agg wasn't supported in older version.
https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-string-functions/sql-server-string_agg-function/

Comment: Fix your data model!  Not knowing how many columns are in a table is just going to make your life really difficult.

Comment: SQL SERVER 2012
@GordonLinoff it's not me that choose how many column. I can't change that model

Comment: SQL SERVER 2012 @Sanpas

Comment: @Sanpas , no they can't. `STRING_AGG` was added in SQL Server 2017... The documentation you linked to even states that: *Applies to: ✓ SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and later"*

Comment: yes sorry in mind was SQL Server 2008.. so you can use FOR XML PATH and STUFF :  http://www.devx.com/tips/database-development/sql/using-for-xml-path-and-stuff-sql-string-concatenation-161031122509.html
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dd111bc9-ec71-48e8-b708-eebd83d680dd/stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server?forum=transactsql

Comment: Considering it being a temp table, I guess it HAS to be created somewhere in your prog - otherwise it would vanish as soon as the creating session ends...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The #TempTable columns can be found by querying tempdb.sys.columns.
So you can write the dynamic sql something like the following...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN DROP TABLE #TempTable; END;

CREATE TABLE #TempTable (
    Column_1 int NOT NULL,
    Column_2 int NOT NULL,
    Column_3 int NOT NULL 
    );

--============================================================

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX) = N'';
SELECT 
    @sql = CONCAT(@sql, N'
        AND t1.', c.name, N' = t2.', c.name)
FROM
    tempdb.sys.columns c
WHERE 
    c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable');

SELECT 
    @sql = CONCAT(N'
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    dbo.table1 t1
    INNER JOIN #table2 t2 
        ON', STUFF(@sql, 1, 7, N''), N';');

PRINT(@sql);
```

The output of the above query...

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    dbo.table1 t1
    INNER JOIN #table2 t2 
        ON t1.Column_1 = t2.Column_1
        AND t1.Column_2 = t2.Column_2
        AND t1.Column_3 = t2.Column_3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `FOR XML PATH`:

```
DECLARE @TabName1 NVARCHAR(100) = '#Tab1';
DECLARE @TabName2 NVARCHAR(100) = '#Tab2';

DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(4000) = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TabName1 + ' INNER JOIN ' + @TabName2 + ' ON ';

WITH cte AS(
SELECT @TabName1 + '.' + ac.name + ' = ' + @TabName2 + '.' + ac2.name as stmtJoin
  FROM tempdb.sys.objects o
  JOIN tempdb.sys.all_columns ac ON ac.object_id = o.object_id
  JOIN tempdb.sys.all_columns ac2 ON ac2.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..' + @TabName2) AND ac.column_id = ac2.column_id
  WHERE o.OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..' + @TabName1)
),
cteStmt AS(
SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT stmtJoin + ' AND '
  FROM cte
  FOR XML PATH('')) cols
  FROM cte
)
SELECT @stmt = @stmt + SUBSTRING(cols, 1, LEN(cols)-4)
  FROM cteStmt

EXEC(@stmt)
```